# Magento 2: on swatch image hover upadate product image on category page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, configurable-swatches

How to update the swatch image on hover rather than click ?

[image]

I have created the custom module to show the color count,here is my code:

```
<?php

namespace Swatch\SwatchCount\Block\Product;

class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct {

public function getProductDetailsHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product) {
   if ($product->getTypeId() == \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE) {

         $_children = $product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($product);
         foreach ($_children as $child){
          $colorarr[$child->getColor()] = $child->getColor();
         }
         if(count($colorarr) > 0) { ?>
            <div class="color-total">
                <?php 
                if(count($colorarr) == 1){
                    $cc= 'Colour';
                }else{
                    $cc= 'Colours';
                }

                echo count($colorarr)." ".$cc; ?>
            </div>
        <?php  }
    }
    $renderer = $this->getDetailsRenderer($product->getTypeId());
    if ($renderer) {
        $renderer->setProduct($product);
        return $renderer->toHtml();
    }
    return '';
}

}
```

Please guide me to do the next part, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom/Configupdate/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer' : 'Custom_Configupdate/js/swatch-renderer',
            'magento-swatch.renderer' : 'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer',
        }
    }
};
```

Custom/Configupdate/view/frontend/web/js/swatch-renderer.js

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'jquery/ui',
  'magento-swatch.renderer'
], function($){


    $(document).on('hover','.product-item-details .swatch-attribute .swatch-option',function($this, $widget){
        var proID= $(this).closest('.product-item-info').attr('id');
        var swatchID = this.id;
        $('#'+proID+' #'+swatchID).click();

    });
});
```

In list.phtml file added `id="prod-id<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"`

```
<div id="prod-id<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" class="product-item-info" data-container="product-grid category-products-grid">
```